# Xamarin.Forms: How to load file.path and save it to sqlite database

Tags: binding, xamarin.forms

I'm using MediaPicker to pick a photo from the device album. I want to display the retrieved image in various parts of my application and for this save it to the sqlite database (as an attribute of an item).

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

The three classes are relevant:

1. the Model, "CodeItem.cs" which implements INotifyPropertyChanged:

   public class CodeItem : INotifyPropertyChanged
   {
       private static string imagepath { get; set; }

   ```
   public static string ImagePath
   {
       get { return imagepath; }
       set
       {
           imagepath = value;
           //OnPropertyChanged("ImagePath");
       }
   }

   public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

   private void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
   {
       if (PropertyChanged != null)
           PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
   }
   ```

   - The backing class of the view CodeItemPage, which contains the listener for the choose image button and is supposed to set the value of ImagePath to the file.Path of the chosen image:

   private async void PickPhotoButton_OnClicked(object sender, EventArgs e)

   ```
   {
       await CrossMedia.Current.Initialize();
       if (!CrossMedia.Current.IsPickPhotoSupported)
       {
           await DisplayAlert("Oh nein", "Pick photo is NotImplementedException supported!", "OK");
           return;
       }
       var file = await CrossMedia.Current.PickPhotoAsync();
       if (file == null)
           return;

       System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(file.Path);
       await DisplayAlert("File Location", file.Path, "OK");

       CodeItem.ImagePath = file.Path;

       System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Variable assigned: " + CodeItem.ImagePath);

   }
   ```

The xaml file CodeItemPage:

```
                <Image Source="{Binding ImagePath}">
                <Image.GestureRecognizers>
                    <TapGestureRecognizer
            Tapped="OnImageClicked"
            NumberOfTapsRequired="1" />
                </Image.GestureRecognizers>
            </Image>

            <Label  Text="{Binding ImagePath}"
                    FontSize="14"
                    TextColor="DarkGray"/>
```

- Error is--> [0:] Binding: 'ImagePath' property not found on 'CodeNote.CodeItem', target property: 'Xamarin.Forms.Image.Source'
- CodeItem.ImagePath = file.Path does assign the value of file.Path to the property ImagePath when excecuting the method *PickPhotoButton_OnClicked*. Still I can't get the image to show up.

Comment: you shouldn't use both binding and explicit assignment of a value on the same element.  Pick one or the other.  Is your BindingContext a CodeItem?  If so, just assign the ImagePath property to file.Path and let binding take care of the UI update for you.  Then your value will be set when you want to save to the db.

Comment: alright thats what i thought. Yes, CodeItem is the BindingContext. 
I set `CodeItem.ImagePath = file.Path;` and  `<Image Source="{Binding ImagePath}"> </Image>` but the image won't show up. 
Still it does show up when i manually type in the path to: `<Entry Text="{Binding ImagePath}" />`. 
Any ideas? Thanks for your help!

Comment: CodeItem needs to implement INotifyPropertyChanged, that is how the bound UI becomes notified of changes to the data

Comment: above i added the implementation of INotifyPropertyChanged, somehow I still cannot set CodeItem.ImagePath = file.path;
-- how would you go about that?

Comment: "i still cannot set" - what does that mean?  Do you get an error or exception?  Where are you trying to set it?

Comment: The backing class for my xaml view contains a listener for the "choose picture" button. Within the listener I load an image from the device gallery and this is also where I'm trying to assign the value of file.path to ImagePath (from my model). I get the error "ImagePath does not exist in that context" - so I somehow need to make ImagePath accessible (but haven't found how yet).

Comment: you need to show more of the relevant code

Comment: Hi Jason, I added my question and at the bottom you should find all the relevant code. please let me know if anything is missing and sorry for the basic questions - I'm just starting with Xamarin.

Comment: why is ImagePath static?  You need to be setting the ImagePath property on the **same instance** of the CodeItem class that you are using as your binding context.

Comment: You're right: `var codenoteItem = (CodeItem)BindingContext; codenoteItem.ImagePath = file.Path;` (ImagePath non-static) works!

Thanks a lot! Your input was very very helpful!